# Rotated shapes in tikz? How should these placed on chains?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am confused about rotated shapes in tikz: I would like to chain together shapes which are not rectangular. How can this be done?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\TAPE[3]{
  \begin{scope}[
                start chain=#1 going below,
                node distance=1,
                every node/.style={
                    on chain=#1,
                    shape=tape,
            minimum width=#2,
                    minimum height=#3,
                    ultra thin,
                    draw=red!75!black,
                    fill=red!5!white,
                    text=black,
                    font=\tiny,
                    align=left,
          tape bend top=none,
          tape bend height=4mm,
            }]
  \node[rotate=0]   (T1) {#2,#3};
  \node[rotate=180] (B1) {};
  \node[rotate=0]   (T2) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B2) {};
  \node[rotate=0]   (T3) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B3) {};
  \node[rotate=0]   (T4) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B4) {};
  \node[rotate=0]   (T5) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B5) {};
  \node[rotate=0]   (T6) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B6) {};
  \end{scope}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\TAPE{a}{1cm}{2cm} % Can we get this to work for any set of parameters?
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like the tight chaining to work for any width and column

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the `node distance` be equal to the `minimum height` (`#3`); nodes without rotation still have to be shifted due to the tape bend; the length for the shifting is precisely the value for the `tape bend height`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newlength\tapebend
\setlength{\tapebend}{4mm}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\TAPE[3]{
  \begin{scope}[
                start chain=#1 going below,
                node distance=#3,
                outer sep=0pt,
                every node/.style={
                    on chain=#1,
                    shape=tape,
                    text width=#2,
                    minimum height=#3,
                    ultra thin,
                    draw=red!75!black,
                    fill=red!5!white,
                    text=black,
                    font=\tiny,
                    align=left,
          tape bend top=none,
          tape bend height=\tapebend,
            }]
  \node[rotate=0]   (T1) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B1) {};
  \node[rotate=0,yshift=4mm]   (T2) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B2) {};
  \node[rotate=0,yshift=4mm]   (T3) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B3) {};
  \node[rotate=0,yshift=4mm]   (T4) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B4) {};
  \node[rotate=0,yshift=4mm]   (T5) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B5) {};
  \node[rotate=0,yshift=4mm]   (T6) {};
  \node[rotate=180] (B6) {};
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\TAPE{a}{1cm}{1.5cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\TAPE{b}{2cm}{1cm}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\TAPE{c}{5mm}{8mm}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]